# Read and Write multiple excel data into one excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to copy the data from multiple excel into one excel. I am novice to python and openpyxl. So i have opened each file and went row by row and copied them. I want to do this with multiple files. How do i loop through row and columns and copy the data consider the column in all the files are same order?

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import workbook

incident_wb = xl.load_workbook('incident resolved yesterday.xlsx')
incident_sheet = incident_wb['Page 1']

combined_wb = xl.Workbook()
combined_sheet = combined_wb.active
combined_sheet.title = "combined_sheet"
combined_wb.save('combined_sheet.xlsx')

for row in range(1, incident_sheet.max_row+1):
incident_no = incident_sheet.cell(row,1)
    opened_date = incident_sheet.cell(row,2)
    shrt_desc   = incident_sheet.cell(row,3)
    requester   = incident_sheet.cell(row,4)
    incdnt_type = incident_sheet.cell(row,5)
    priority    = incident_sheet.cell(row,6)
    assgn_grp   = incident_sheet.cell(row,7)
    assgn_to    = incident_sheet.cell(row,8)
    updated     = incident_sheet.cell(row,9)
    status      = incident_sheet.cell(row,10)
    sub_status  = incident_sheet.cell(row,11)
    ##copy the data into the new sheet
    incident_no_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,1)
    incident_no_1.value = incident_no.value
    opened_date_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,2)
    opened_date_1.value = opened_date.value
    shrt_desc_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,3)
    shrt_desc_1.value = shrt_desc.value
    requester_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,4)
    requester_1.value = requester.value
    incdnt_type_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,5)
    incdnt_type_1.value = incdnt_type.value
    priority_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,6)
    priority_1.value = priority.value
    assgn_grp_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,7)
    assgn_grp_1.value = assgn_grp.value
    assgn_to_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,8)
    assgn_to_1.value = assgn_to.value
    updated_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,9)
    updated_1.value = updated.value
    status_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,10)
    status_1.value = status.value
    sub_status_1 = combined_sheet.cell(row,11)
    sub_status_1.value = sub_status.value
    ##print(f"The incident resolved yesterday {incident_no.value}")

combined_wb.save('combined_sheet.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to build a list of date from multiple excel files and then write it to another file.

**As a proof of concept:**

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import workbook

def provide_data(workbookName, sheetName):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(workbookName)
    sheet = wb[sheetName]
    return [[y.value for y in x] for x in sheet.iter_rows()] 
    # This creates an array of rows, which contain an array of cell values.
    # It will be much better to provide mapping for cells and return business object.

def save_data(list_of_sheets):
    combined_wb = xl.Workbook()
    combined_sheet = combined_wb.active
    combined_sheet.title = "combined_sheet"
    for sheet in list_of_sheets:
        for row in sheet:
            combined_sheet.append(row) # combining multiple rows.
    combined_wb.save('combined_sheet.xlsx')

workSheetsToCopy = [['incident resolved yesterday.xlsx', 'Page 1'], ['other.xlsx', 'Page 1']]

workSheetsToCopy = [provide_data(x[0], x[1]) for x in workSheetsToCopy]
save_data(workSheetsToCopy)
```

Comment: Greg, This works really Great. But i want to limit the iter_rows() with only few columns, say col A to col K. Also i want to remove the first row in each of the sheet because thats the col heading which is repeating again and again

Comment: .iter_rows() allows you to specify rows using min_row and max_row. So assuming you want to skip the first row and grab up to (and including) K. Try sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=11) (you'll probably want to pass the values as parameters). See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows